# Simple .htaccess to nginx

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, nginx

I need help how to convert this simple .htaccess to ngingx format and i really have no idea where to start with it. I tried to go through nginx docs but they simply overwhelmed me and I need it done now so please help :)

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/host/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/host/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
rewrite  (.*)  /app/host$1;
```

in your `server {  .. }`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as it doesn't pass the $1 to application and just looks for /app/host/whatever/was/my/nice/link

Comment: app/host/$1 looks like what you need. can u give me more example.